# DataBinding Scope in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, scope

This is probably one of those things that I could test myself, but I wanted to get a more inclusive answer from someone who understands databinding a little better than I do. I'm more of a model-intensive MVC guy myself, so I'm a little new the whole concept of asp.net data binding in general.

So here's what I do understand: you bind a control or entire page to a datasource, and then you can use the `DataBinder` class to help resolve data at runtime.

What I don't quite get is the scope. For example, the legacy app I recently inherited has a lot of lines like this:

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "saved_offer_id");
```

But I'm confused as to how asp.net knows where to look to find the `saved_offer_id` key. For example, lets say we have two repeaters, like this:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repeater1">
     <span>My offer ID is <# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "saved_offer_id") %></span>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Repeater id="repeater2">
     <span>My offer ID is <# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "saved_offer_id") %></span>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And let's say that each of the repeaters has its own data source. How does the `DataBinder` know which data source to look in? Is there a situation where those two repeaters could display a differ offer id value?

Comment: The DataBinder uses the DataSource associated with it's parent object

Comment: @AntLaC that's kind of what I was looking for. That brings up another question, though. What about nested controls? Like, a repeater inside a repeater, both with their own data source. Would the nested repeater then have access to both sources?

Comment: Not really, not in the sense I believe your question is asking. The nested reader can read the values of the current record of it's parent reader

Comment: @AntLaC Ok, thanks. Another question, too. I know (thanks to you) that it uses its parent control's data source, but how does it know what its parent control is? I guess the `<# ... %>` blocks have access to both the server and the DOM?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact technical reasons, but basically whatever control it's wrapped in is it's parent. If you look at the rendered HTML, you will see how the controls inside the repeaters will have the repeater name prefixed in their ID

Comment: @AntLaC Yeah, I was looking more for the technical reasons behind it. I was just a little curious about the databinding code-blocks and how they work behind the scenes. No big deal though, you've already answered all of the questions I really needed answers. If you'd like to convert this conversation to an answer I'll gladly upvote/accept. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The DataBinder uses the DataSource associated with it's parent object.

The nested reader can read the values of the current record of it's parent reader.